# Display a custom text based on product category in WooCommerce Email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, email-notifications

I'm trying to display some "conditional" custom text on the "Order Complete" email, which is sent to the customers when an order is marked as completed. I have used [the following code](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-extra-content-order-email/).

Now, I want to make this code conditional, so this code should only be active for the "Gift" Category products. I couldn't find any appropriate Woocommerce functions for this particular functionality.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is what I have for now:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 
'bbloomer_add_content_specific_email', 20, 4 );

function bbloomer_add_content_specific_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    if ( $email->id == 'customer_completed_order' ) {
        echo '<p class="email-text-conditional">Thank you for your order with Adventure Clues, we have sent your recipient the gift card’</p>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'email_before_order_table_conditional_display', 20, 4 );
function email_before_order_table_conditional_display( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    // Only for "commpeted" order status notification
    if ( 'customer_completed_order' !== $email->id ) return;

    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ){
        if( has_term( "Gifts", "product_cat", $item->get_product_id() ) ){
            echo '<p class="email-text-conditional">Thank you for your order with Adventure Clues, we have sent your recipient the gift card.</p>';
            break;
        }
        if( has_term( "Clothes", "product_cat", $item->get_product_id() ) ){
            echo '<p class="email-text-conditional">Thank you for your order with Adventure Clues, we are managing your Clothes.</p>';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.