# Add custom text 'per item' based on product category in WooCommerce email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, email-notifications

How to add a custom text 'per item' based on product category on all WooCommerce emails?

Therefore I tried to modify [Add a custom text for a particular product on specific email notification in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53151755/11987538) and [Display a custom text based on product category in WooCommerce Email](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50568684/11987538) answer code to my needs.

```php
// Setting the email_is as a global variable
add_action('woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'the_email_id_as_a_global', 1, 4);
function the_email_id_as_a_global($order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){
    $GLOBALS['email_id_str'] = $email->id;
}

// Displaying product description in new email notifications
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'product_description_in_new_email_notification', 10, 3 );
function product_description_in_new_email_notification( $product_cat, $cat, $order = null ){
    // HERE define your targetted product CAT
    $targeted_id = 'x';

    // HERE define the text information to be displayed for the targeted product id
    $text_information = __("There is an offer in this particular item", "woocommerce");

    // Getting the email ID global variable
    $refNameGlobalsVar = $GLOBALS;
    $email_id = $refNameGlobalsVar['email_id_str'];

    // If empty email ID we exit
    if(empty($email_id)) return;

    // Only for "New Order email notification" for your targeted product ID
    if ( 'customer_completed_order' == $email_id && 'new_order' == $email_id 
        in_array( $targeted_id, array( $cat->get_product_cat(), $item->get_variation_id() ) ) ) {

        // Display the text
        echo '<div class="product-text" style="margin-top:10px"><p>' . $text_information . '</p></div>';
    }
}
```

Unfortunately without the desired result. I would like to display custom text under an order item name for all products of a particular product category in all email notifications (this is per item, not per email). Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes on your code attempt:

- `$product_cat` and `$cat` do not exist as arguments for the `woocommerce_order_item_meta_end` hook
- `$cat->get_product_cat()` does not exist and is incorrect
- Use `has_term()` WordPress function to check if the current post has any of given terms

So you get:

```php
// Setting global variable
function action_woocommerce_email_before_order_table( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    $GLOBALS['email_data'] = array(
        'email_id'  => $email->id, // The email ID (to target specific email notification)
        'is_email'  => true // When it concerns a WooCommerce email notification
    );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'action_woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 1, 4 );

// Displaying description
function action_woocommerce_order_item_meta_end( $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text ) {
    // Getting the custom 'email_data' global variable
    $ref_name_globals_var = $GLOBALS;
    
    // Isset & NOT empty
    if ( isset ( $ref_name_globals_var ) && ! empty( $ref_name_globals_var ) ) {
        // Isset
        $email_data = isset( $ref_name_globals_var['email_data'] ) ? $ref_name_globals_var['email_data'] : '';
        
        // NOT empty
        if ( ! empty( $email_data ) ) {
            // Specific categories: the term name/term_id/slug. Several could be added, separated by a comma
            $categories = array( 108, 1, 'categorie-1' );

            // The text information
            $text_information = __( 'There is an offer in this particular item', 'woocommerce' );

            // Specific email notifications: multiple statuses can be added, separated by a comma
            $email_ids = array( 'new_order', 'customer_processing_order', 'customer_completed_order', 'customer_on_hold_order' );

            // Targeting specific email notifications AND check if the current post has any of given terms
            if ( in_array( $email_data['email_id'], $email_ids ) && has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $item->get_product_id() ) ) {
                // Display the text
                echo '<p>' . $text_information . '</p>';
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'action_woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: Perfect answer! 

Thank-you for your words. I'm very beginner at coding - will continue to learn.